# Expo react-native use css-loader

Tags: javascript, react-native, webpack, expo

I am pretty new with Expo and react-native. I am facing a problem to load styles as module with css-loader. I tried a lot of things to customize the webpack.config.js with [Expo documentation](https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-webpack/) but it doesn't work !

If someone can help, I would be so grateful because I spent so many times on this problem...

Reproduce issue:

```
expo init my-app
```

My webpack.config.js

```
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require('@expo/webpack-config');

module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
    const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(
    {
        ...env,
        module: {
            rules: [
                    {
                        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                        exclude: /node_modules/,
                        use: {
                            loader: "babel-loader"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.css$/,
                        loader: "style-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.css$/,
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                        }
                    }
                ],
            },
        extensions: [ '.web.js', '.js', '.jsx', '.css' ],
        },
    argv
    );
    return config;
};
```

My component: menu.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './menu.module.css';
console.log(styles); // Displaying {}

class Menu extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div className={styles.red}>a</div>
    }
}

export default Menu;
```

My style: menu.module.css

```
.red {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Unfortunately css-loader won't work with react-native/expo.
  for more information regarding styling Follow [react-native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/style)

if you want to write style like normal css, have a look on [styled-componenet](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics)

- div tag will not work with react-native.Replacement of div in
  react-native we have View and fragment.

Comment: Is there any replacement of css-loader for expo ? i was looking of 'react-native-css-transformer' do you know if this is working ? i tried and i can't make it work ...

Comment: react-native-css-transformer is metro plugin. and it works with bare react-native. it won't work with expo.

Comment: Why wouldn't css loader work? While RNW components use custom styling solution you could still style HTML/React components using external css and className

Comment: I found this to be useful: https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-css-modules/blob/master/docs/web-compatibility.md